# Operation not valid due to current state of the object error in IronRuby

Tags: c#, ironruby, invalidoperationexception

I have a ruby script that telnets into something and creates an output file.

I am trying to call the script by using the following code:

```
ScriptEngine rubyengine = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateEngine();
rubyengine.ExecuteFile(@"\Documents\query.rb");
```

and am getting an 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error.

the ruby script runs flawlessly when executed individually outside of the code, so I know it works fine.

Any ideas?

I am using .NET 4 and the newest version of IronRuby

Comment: Is there an alternate way to give it the path of the file to execute?  I'm afraid that `\Documents` will go down to `C:\Documents`, which is rarely what people actually want in this situation.

Comment: My code has the absolute path to the file in that parameter, unfortunately I'm working on a classified system and cant share the full path.

Comment: That's fine, I wouldn't expect anyone to post real absolute paths even if they were working on a throwaway VM.  I was just concerned that might be part of a deeper problem, but apparently it isn't.